# how to find xpath if tag attribute is not fixed

Tags: xml, xpath

I need to check xpath of following xml code but my tag keeps on changing.. for example in below response, tag ns2:Response is not fixed sometimes it comes as ns1:Response or ns3:Response anything.... please help.

```
<ns2:Response>
    <ns2:ResponseCode>00</ns2:ResponseCode>
    <ns2:ResponseMessage>Success</ns2:ResponseMessage>
</ns2:Response>
```

Comment: have you tried *:ResponseCode in your xpath query?

Comment: I've tried //ns*:ResponseCode but it didn't work.

Comment: try //*[local-name()='ResponseCode'] then

Comment: I have been using OR operator to fetch the result but I think thats not the proper solution to it... there might be something else that could resolve this issue. //ns1:ResponseCode | //ns2:ResponseCode OR so on....

Comment: thanks...its working can you please explain your method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i mentioned in my comments, you can use *[local-names()='ResponseCode'] to reach your element without worrying about it's namespace.

and also my first solution would work as well, you just cant mix it like `ns*:ResponseCode`, `*:ResponseCode` should work

To learn more visit [here](http://developer.marklogic.com/blog/namespace-wildcards-in-xpath)